# регистрация и авторизация в приложении через vk

Tags: vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Я создал мобильное приложение, у которого есть серверная часть с логикой и базой данных. И вот мне бы хотелось дать пользователям возможность регистрироваться и проходить авторизацию при помощи их ВК-данных. Такой способ я уже реализовал в рамках своего сайта, а вот с мобильным устройством возникли трудности. Возможно, я просто не понимаю, суть.

Мне надо из мобильного устройства отправить запрос на авторизацию ВК, получить токен как в мобильное устройство, так и на мой сервер, и в последующем уже через userid и token обращаться от клиента к моему серверу и получать данные от пользователя. В случае, если такого userid в базе еще нет, он должен быть там создан.

Варианта обращения в OAuth есть два -- клиентский, получающий сразу token и серверный, который работает через code с дальнейшим запросом token.

Если я делаю запрос через implicit flow, я получаю в фрагменте токен, но так как фрагмент uri не отправляется на сервер, у меня эти данные будут только в приложении.

Неужели мне нужно из приложения делать запрос  на сервер, с него вызывать авторизацию в вк через authorization code flow и потом в браузере приложения это как-то выхватывать? Не уверен, что так вообще возможно.

Или же ответ прост и очевиден и я его не нашел?! Спасибо.

Comment: Зачем вам токен на сервере? Что вы с ним собираетесь делать? В клиентском приложении он не должен отправляться на ваш сервер или сервера каких-то третьих лиц.

Comment: ну смотрите, у меня на сервере почта пользователя, мне нужно залогиниться и прочитать ее. Я логинюсь через вк, получаю юзер айди и токен. Как мне теперь авторизоваться на моем сервере, имея на клиенте юзер айди и токен? На сервере у меня только юзер айди.

Comment: оу. тогда тут только через explict flow - иначе в текущем варианте даже получая токен, то вы никак не сможете проверить что пришел он от именно этого пользователя ВК. Тогда обратный вопрос - зачем вам вообще понадобился токен на клиенте? :)

Comment: ну как зачем? обращение клиента к серверу, как мне казалось, всегда пара -- id + токен. Получить их можно либо залогинившись через имя и пароль, тогда на сервере создается новый токен и клиенту приходит id+token, через которые он делает все последующие запросы к серверу, либо id и token передаются серверу и клиенту от вк. но, как мне казалось, они должны быть и у клиента, и у сервера

Comment: Нет. То, что вы описываете - вовсе не OAuth-токен, а идентификатор сессии - уникальное значение, генерируемое сервером и отданное клиенту при его успешной авторизации - это значение ни в коем случае не должно быть идентичным OAuth-токену. Оно служит для сохранения клиента в авторизованном состоянии в течение нужного периода времени. ID клиента тут лишнее, кстати - сервер его итак может получить по идентификатору сессии.

Comment: я понимаю, но любой на сервере генерируемый токен требует авторизации. В одном случае это переданный логин и пароль, как должен сервер распознать человека, получившего на клиенте OAuth-token, чтобы выдать ему токен сессии?!